# Rendering an infinite number of items accordion-style in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I understand how to render accordion/collapsible elements in React JS, and even how to do multiple on one page. However, none of the methods I've seen account for a case where you're attempting to render an unknown number of items under their own section header.

For instance, to render these items' section headers I know to do:

`{content.stuff.map(thing => <div> {thing[0]}</div>)}`

where stuff is a list of lists, where the inner lists have a known number of elements, but it's unknown how many inner lists there are.

And to render the rest of the information, I know to lock it behind something like:

`{showItem && content.stuff.map(thing => <div> {thing} </div>)}`

all in my return ().

This method will obviously expand all of them at once. And though I understand the tutorials mentioning how to render 2,3, etc accordion sections with labels and such, I'm just not seeing much applicable to my situation. They always involve specifically assigning some indicator of uniqueness to each section of collapsible content, which is impossible if you don't actually know how many sections you will have.

Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code in a context: provide a function that renders it? Also, where do you get the sections from? I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by infinite... do you mean that you never know how many sections are given to you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m not sure I can. This is for a pseudo-internship and I’m not supposed to even share the code. Essentially, there’s a database of many agencies a user can be matched to, and there’s no way for me to know exactly how many a given user will be matched to. I want to display the agency name as a collapsible button and have the agency info listed underneath.

Comment: @Seren did you find the answer to this